# SQL Server : query fails when using TOP or Order By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This query returns the correct results.

```
SELECT 
   a.Company, a.FiscalYear, a.FiscalPeriod,
   a.JournalCode, a.JournalNum, a.JournalLine, a.Description,
   a.JEDate, a.GroupID, a.PostedBy, a.PostedDate,
   a.SourceModule,
   b_1.PartDescription, b_1.PartNum, b_1.PONum,
   b_1.POLine, b_1.VendorID, b_1.VendorNum, b_1.VendorName
FROM   
   epicor905.dbo.GLJrnDtl AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       a.Company, a.TranNum, a.TranDate, a.PartNum, a.WareHouseCode, a.TranQty,
       a.MtlUnitCost, a.ExtCost, a.PONum, a.POLine, a.PORelNum, a.PartDescription,
       a.VendorNum, c.VendorID, c.Name AS VendorName, a.POUnitCost, a.POReceiptQty,
       a.GLTrans, a.PostedToGL, b.JournalNum, b.JournalLine, b.JournalCode, 
       b.FiscalYear
    FROM   
       epicor905.dbo.PartTran AS a
    INNER JOIN 
       epicor905.dbo.TranGLC AS b ON a.Company = b.Company
                                  AND a.SysDate_ = b.Key1
                                  AND a.SysTime = b.Key2
                                  AND a.TranNum = b.Key3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       epicor905.dbo.Vendor AS c ON a.Company = c.Company
                                 AND a.VendorNum = c.VendorNum
    WHERE  
       (b.RelatedToFile = 'PartTran')
       AND (a.PostedToGL = 1 )) AS b_1 ON a.Company = b_1.Company
                                        AND a.JournalCode = b_1.JournalCode
                                        AND a.FiscalYear = b_1.FiscalYear
                                        AND a.JournalNum = b_1.JournalNum
                                        AND a.JournalLine = b_1.JournalLine
WHERE  
    (a.FiscalYear = 2014)
```

The following queries do not work.

They all fail with

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have tried using `ISDATE(col) == 1` in my `JOIN` clause but it didn't seem to help.

Added `TOP(10)`:

```
SELECT TOP(10) a.Company,a.FiscalYear,a.FiscalPeriod,a.JournalCode,a.JournalNum,a.JournalLine,a.Description,
              a.JEDate,a.GroupID,a.PostedBy,a.PostedDate,a.SourceModule,b_1.PartDescription,b_1.PartNum,b_1.PONum,
              b_1.POLine,b_1.VendorID,b_1.VendorNum,b_1.VendorName
FROM   epicor905.dbo.GLJrnDtl AS a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a.Company,a.TranNum,a.TranDate,a.PartNum,a.WareHouseCode,a.TranQty,a.MtlUnitCost,a.ExtCost,
                               a.PONum,a.POLine,a.PORelNum,a.PartDescription,a.VendorNum,c.VendorID,c.Name AS VendorName,
                               a.POUnitCost,a.POReceiptQty,a.GLTrans,a.PostedToGL,b.JournalNum,b.JournalLine,b.JournalCode,b.FiscalYear
                        FROM   epicor905.dbo.PartTran AS a
                               INNER JOIN epicor905.dbo.TranGLC AS b
                                       ON a.Company = b.Company
                                          AND a.SysDate_ = b.Key1
                                          AND a.SysTime = b.Key2
                                          AND a.TranNum = b.Key3
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN epicor905.dbo.Vendor AS c
                                            ON a.Company = c.Company
                                               AND a.VendorNum = c.VendorNum
                        WHERE  ( b.RelatedToFile = 'PartTran' )
                               AND ( a.PostedToGL = 1 )) AS b_1
                    ON a.Company = b_1.Company
                       AND a.JournalCode = b_1.JournalCode
                       AND a.FiscalYear = b_1.FiscalYear
                       AND a.JournalNum = b_1.JournalNum
                       AND a.JournalLine = b_1.JournalLine
WHERE  ( a.FiscalYear = 2014 )
```

*Added Order By*

```
SELECT a.Company,a.FiscalYear,a.FiscalPeriod,a.JournalCode,a.JournalNum,a.JournalLine,a.Description,
       a.JEDate,a.GroupID,a.PostedBy,a.PostedDate,a.SourceModule,b_1.PartDescription,b_1.PartNum,b_1.PONum,
       b_1.POLine,b_1.VendorID,b_1.VendorNum,b_1.VendorName
FROM   epicor905.dbo.GLJrnDtl AS a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a.Company,a.TranNum,a.TranDate,a.PartNum,a.WareHouseCode,a.TranQty,a.MtlUnitCost,a.ExtCost,
                               a.PONum,a.POLine,a.PORelNum,a.PartDescription,a.VendorNum,c.VendorID,c.Name AS VendorName,a.POUnitCost,
                               a.POReceiptQty,a.GLTrans,a.PostedToGL,b.JournalNum,b.JournalLine,b.JournalCode,b.FiscalYear
                        FROM   epicor905.dbo.PartTran AS a
                               INNER JOIN epicor905.dbo.TranGLC AS b
                                       ON a.Company = b.Company
                                          AND a.SysDate_ = b.Key1
                                          AND a.SysTime = b.Key2
                                          AND a.TranNum = b.Key3
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN epicor905.dbo.Vendor AS c
                                            ON a.Company = c.Company
                                               AND a.VendorNum = c.VendorNum
                        WHERE  ( b.RelatedToFile = 'PartTran' )
                               AND ( a.PostedToGL = 1 )) AS b_1
                    ON a.Company = b_1.Company
                       AND a.JournalCode = b_1.JournalCode
                       AND a.FiscalYear = b_1.FiscalYear
                       AND a.JournalNum = b_1.JournalNum
                       AND a.JournalLine = b_1.JournalLine
WHERE  ( a.FiscalYear = 2014 )
ORDER  BY a.JournalNum
```

Also here is some information about this from epicor.

```
Summary:        XA How to determine Key fields in TranGLC table?
Book:           Support Solutions
Page:           10175MPS

PAGE:  10175MPS  Updated: 11/21/2012

PROBLEM:
XA How to determine Key fields in TranGLC table?  The fields will be different depending on the TranGLC.RelatedToFile.

RESOLUTION:
In order to determine this, you need to find the Primary Index for the RelatedToFile's table.

1. Open Data Dictionary Viewer
2. Tools > Personalization
3. Click in the Indexes grid and select the pulldown on the "Collections" and uncheck the "Hidden" checkbox for PrimaryIndex
4. Select the RelatedToFile table in the Data Dictionary
5. View the Primary Index for that table
**The Key fields will be listed in order separated by a comma.  The Company field is not included as the first Key field in the TranGLC table, so that field can be ignored.**

Example:
TranGLC.RelatedToFile = PartTran
The Primary Index for PartTran = sysdttime
*Note the Index fields for the primary index (Company,SysDate,SysTime,TranNum)*
**Company will not be one of the Key fields**
Key1 = SysDate
Key2 = SysTime
Key3 = TranNum

VERSION:
9.04.503
```

Comment: `a.SysDate_ = b.Key1 a.SysTime = b.Key2` what are the `data type` of those fields? I'm guessing that they are not the same.

Comment: @Sam Sadly they are not and I don't have any control over that.

Comment: There's your issue. The conversation error is happening because of that not because of `order by or top..` What is the data type for `b.Key1`?

Comment: @Sam b.Key1 is a `VARCHAR`. Epicor uses the `Keyx` fields to store joining information. According to them anything with `b.RelatedToFile = 'PartTran'` will have `b.Key1 = date`, `b.Key2 = time`, and `b.Key3 = int`. Also the only time this query fails is when I add TOP() or Order By.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Epicor", but try converting your `date` field to varchar and then do a join. And for your `b.Key2` and `b.Key3` convert according to the data type.

Answer (score 2):

The failing of your query has nothing to do with either `TOP` or `ORDER BY`. The problem is that, somewhere in this query, you are comparing or joining one column of type `DATETIME` and another of type `(N)VARCHAR`, and the latter column contains a value somewhere that cannot be converted to a `DATETIME`. By adding `TOP` or `ORDER BY`, the optimizer is just constructing a different execution plan that exposes the problematic data -- that the first query works without hitting the troublesome rows is pure luck.

Can you include the schemas of your tables? If you know the problematic columns, you can fix the conversion problem by converting your `DATETIME` column to `VARCHAR` explicitly in the `JOIN` (that is, `FROM a JOIN b ON a.string_col = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), b.date_col, 120)`, or whatever format is appropriate) so the engine doesn't try to do it the other way around and fail.

Comment: It is impossible for me to change the schema. This is for an ERP system. [This Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474647/mssql-query-fails-when-using-top-or-order-by/26474756#comment41587177_26474647) should explain it.  Also do do you still need the schema? It is fairly large...

Comment: If you know the offending columns, the schema isn't needed.

Comment: I thought you suggested to modify the schema the first time I read it. Oops!

Comment: I just tried this but I was not able to get it to work. I will have to lookup how to use `CONVERT()` some more.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the optimization engine will sometime not bother to look at the WHERE before it does the conversions.  In the past you had to make a sub-query to only select items with the correct type and then do the cast in an outer select (which could be slower).

However, newer versions of SQL include TRY_CAST.  Now you can use TRY_CAST in the join statements. This function returns null when it fails to convert so it won't stop the query from running just that line's join -- this is the desired behavior.  Should have no issues using it.

Like this:

```
SELECT    
  a.Company, a.FiscalYear, a.FiscalPeriod, a.JournalCode, a.JournalNum, a.JournalLine, a.Description, a.JEDate, a.GroupID, a.PostedBy, 
  a.PostedDate, a.SourceModule, b_1.PartDescription, b_1.PartNum, b_1.PONum, b_1.POLine, b_1.VendorID, b_1.VendorNum, b_1.VendorName
FROM epicor905.dbo.GLJrnDtl AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT
     a.Company, a.TranNum, a.TranDate, a.PartNum, a.WareHouseCode, a.TranQty, a.MtlUnitCost, a.ExtCost, a.PONum, a.POLine, a.PORelNum, 
     a.PartDescription, a.VendorNum, c.VendorID, c.Name AS VendorName, a.POUnitCost, a.POReceiptQty, a.GLTrans, a.PostedToGL, b.JournalNum, 
     b.JournalLine, b.JournalCode, b.FiscalYear
   FROM epicor905.dbo.PartTran AS a 
   INNER JOIN epicor905.dbo.TranGLC AS b 
      ON a.Company = b.Company AND a.SysDate_ = TRY_CAST(b.Key1 AS DATE) AND a.SysTime = TRY_CAST(b.Key2 AS TIME) AND a.TranNum = b.Key3 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN epicor905.dbo.Vendor AS c 
      ON a.Company = c.Company AND a.VendorNum = c.VendorNum
   WHERE
     (b.RelatedToFile = 'PartTran') AND (a.PostedToGL = 1)
  ) AS b_1 
   ON  a.Company = b_1.Company 
   AND a.JournalCode = b_1.JournalCode 
   AND a.FiscalYear = b_1.FiscalYear 
   AND a.JournalNum = b_1.JournalNum 
   AND a.JournalLine = b_1.JournalLine
WHERE     (a.FiscalYear = 2014)
```

Part of interest:

```
... a.SysDate_ = TRY_CAST(b.Key1 AS DATE) AND a.SysTime = TRY_CAST(b.Key2 AS TIME) ...
```

Microsoft reference documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx

Comment: I just tried this but I can't use `TRY_CAST` since Sql Server 2008 R2 doesn't support it.